# Change of variables in double integral - what's wrong?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, integral-transforms

I have a homework problem, as follows:

> Evaluate the double integral by making an appropriate change of
>   variables.
>
> > $\iint_R 9\sin(49x^2+16y^2)\,dA$, where $R$ is the region in the first
> >     quadrant bounded by the ellipse $49x^2 + 16y^2 = 1$

My work is as follows:

- Let $x\overset{\Delta}=\tfrac17u\cos v$ and $y\overset\Delta=\tfrac14u\sin v$.
- The Jacobian is the determinant $$|J|=\begin{Vmatrix}
  \tfrac17\cos v & -\tfrac17u\sin v\\ 
  \tfrac14\sin v & \tfrac14u\cos v
  \end{Vmatrix}=28u\cos^2v+28u\sin^2v=\tfrac u{28}\\
  $$
- The limits of integration are $u\in[0,1]$, $v\in[0,\pi/2]$.
- The integral is $$\frac9{28}\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^1u\sin u^2\,du\,dv$$ which evaluates to $\frac9{112\pi}(1-\cos(1))$.

However, my WebAssign (online grading system) says that this is incorrect.

Where have I gone wrong?

I would be happy to provide more detailed work for any step if it would be helpful or necessary.

**EDIT:** I've done some additional research and found a couple questions on the world's most authoritative source for math help that seem to give similar answers ([here](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130402103712AAwDAiC) and [here](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080131163349AAyHB6m)); am I missing something?

Comment: Well, from the top of my head - it looks like you have $\pi$ placed wrong, at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\frac 9{28} \int_0^{\frac \pi 2} \int_0^1 u \sin u^2 du dv = \frac {9 \pi}{112} \left[ 1 - \cos (1)\right]
$$